# How to create static worksheet XLSX

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, xlsx

I want to create XLSX, but I want to create empty XLSX, it means that I won't pass there any json but static values.
So, I want to add to cell A1 string "Example 1", cell B8 "This is cell cell B8", to cell F4321 string "WOW" etc.

My problem is:

```
  const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.reportPayment,
    {  });
```

and when I use:

```
 worksheet['A1'].v = 'This is cell A1';
```

I get the error:

> Cannot convert undefined or null to object

I think problem is in this first part.

Comment: IIRC Angular doesn't have built-in XLSX support. Is this js-xlsx, a.k.a. SheetJS? I don't know that but some other XLSX generators need you to add rows to the spreadsheet before you can read or write cells in them.

Comment: @Rup this is page from I install xlsx to my project https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx